# How to enable togglz-console in spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, togglz

My spring-boot+jersey application has integrated togglz. I added below dependencies as below.

```
// togglz
compile('org.togglz:togglz-servlet:'+togglzVersion)
compile('org.togglz:togglz-cdi:'+togglzVersion)
compile('javax.enterprise:cdi-api:2.0-EDR1')
compile('org.togglz:togglz-spring-web:'+togglzVersion)
compile("org.togglz:togglz-spring-boot-starter:"+togglzVersion)
compile("org.togglz:togglz-console:"+togglzVersion)
compile("org.togglz:togglz-spring-security:"+togglzVersion)
compile("com.github.heneke.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-extras-togglz:1.0.1.RELEASE")
```

In my boot class I added below code:

```
@Bean
public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
    return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(AppFeatures.class);
}
```

after launch the app, I can see the json data from this link:http://localhost:8080/togglz.
But I can't access http://localhost:8080/togglz-console. I got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden" error.

I can see below log in my log file but I can't access togglz-console/*.

```
o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'togglzConsoleServlet' to [/togglz-console/*]
```

below is my togglz property file:

```
# togglz
togglz:
    feature-enums: com.cooltoo.backend.features.AppFeatures # Comma-separated list of fully-qualified feature enum class names.
    features:
        SMS_CODE: false
    console:
        enabled: true # Enable admin console.
        path: /togglz-console # The path of the admin console when enabled.
```

what did I miss here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step1** Add the below dependency :

```
   <!-- Togglz Admin Console -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
       <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.0.RC1</version>
   </dependency>
```

**Step2** Add the below in your application.yml or application.properties

```
togglz:
  console:
    enabled: true # Enable admin console.
```

or

```
togglz.console.enabled: true # Enable admin console.
```

**Step3** Configure the console path by

```
togglz:
    console:
     path: /togglz-console # The path of the admin console when enabled.
```

For authentication : Add a dummy UserProvider which assigns admin privileges to every user:

```
public class MyTogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {
        @Override
        public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
            return new UserProvider() {
                @Override
                public FeatureUser getCurrentUser() {
                    return new SimpleFeatureUser("admin", true);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

If you want to authenticate the user, instead of the above dummy one , implement your own UserProvider by following this [documentation](http://www.togglz.org/documentation/authentication.html)

Comment: I edited the togglz property setting and now I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below in your application.yml or application.properties:

```
togglz:
  console:
    enabled: true
    path: /togglz-console
    use-management-port: false
```

or

```
togglz.console.enabled: true
togglz.console.path: /togglz-console
togglz.console.use-management-port: false
```

Setting togglz.console.use-management-port to false will always run the Admin Console on the application port.